# Text Gradient on spark.label in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, gradient, flex-spark

I am using **spark.label** for Mobiles in Flex, I want gradient on label text instead of solid color. But performance should be kept in mind as it will run on mobile device.

How can I achieve this ?

**Thanks**.

Comment: You should definitely check this out [link](http://flexforcefive.com/wordpress/?p=506) Looks pretty easy to be done

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
<s:BorderContainer>
    <s:backgroundFill>
        <s:LinearGradient rotation="180">
            <s:GradientEntry color="0x666666"/>
            <s:GradientEntry color="0xCCCCCC"/>
        </s:LinearGradient>
    </s:backgroundFill>
    <s:Label text="G R A D I E N T" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"/>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

Comment: I think this will fill the background not the text ? I don't want gradient in background, I need it only on Text.. any idea ?

Comment: ah yes, using s:Graphic and s:mask, as @awq pointed out, seems like the way to go...